# Mysql update using WHERE in

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to tweak the following query to add 1 to `col` in multiple rows.

```
UPDATE table
SET col=col+1
WHERE id in (1,2,3)
```

It doesn't work, I think because I'm not updating `col` with the same data, it's adding 1 to whatever's already there.

I can get the following queries to work, but can't figure out how to achieve what I want without using multiple queries to replace the above single one.

```
UPDATE table
SET col=col+1
WHERE id =1
```

...successfully adds 1 to col in row 1.

```
UPDATE table
SET col=9
WHERE id in (1,2,3)
```

...successfully makes col = 9 in rows 1,2 and 3

Is there a way to tweak the first query to work?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. What are the current values of col, and what do you want them to be after the update?

Comment: I don't get it : your first query is perfectly correct until I miss something. I suspect an error in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET col = case when id = 1 
               then col+1
               else 9
          end
WHERE id in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Hi - col is a counter, so it can be different for each row.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys - I've just got back to working on this.  I'll go back and check that my testing was correct, but it looks like Juergen's query would do the job regardless.